# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inputs')

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ethernet, ethers.js, ether

I'm encountering an error while trying to decode logs using the **`web3.eth.abi.decodeLog`** function in my JavaScript code. The error message I'm receiving is "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inputs')". I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue.

[image]

I'm trying to decode logs from a transaction using the **`web3.eth.abi.decodeLog`** function. I'm iterating through the logs and attempting to find the corresponding event ABI using **`contractABI.find`** based on the topic signature. However, when trying to access the **`inputs`** property of the **`eventAbi`** object, I encounter the "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inputs')" error.